# How to use replace multiple digits with a single character

Tags: regex, linux, bash

The code below turns a string `abcd-efj-klmnop-3.7.1.txt` to `abcd-efj-klmnop-*.*.*.txt` while I would like it to be `abcd-efj-klmnop-*.txt` (with a single star). How to achieve it?

```
FILE_NAME="abcd-efj-klmnop-3.7.1.txt"
WILD_NAME=${FILE_NAME//[0-9]/*} 
echo $WILD_NAME
```

Comment: Will you always have 3 numbers before the extension?

Comment: You need to be specific on what you are trying to replace.  Things between last hyphen and the extension? Or digits and dot before extension? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this pattern:

```
FILE_NAME="abcd-efj-klmnop-3.7.1.txt"
WILD_NAME=${FILE_NAME//[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/*} 
echo $WILD_NAME
```

The extra part `(\.[0-9]+)*` looks for a dot followed by one or more numerals, any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try:

```
WILD_NAME=$(sed 's/[0-9]\{1,\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,\}\)*/*/' <<< "$FILE_NAME")
```

If your `bash` supports `shopt` builtin, you can also say:

```
shopt -s extglob
WILD_NAME=${FILE_NAME/+([0-9])*(\.+([0-9]))/*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not robust enough but if the pattern is the same, a PE solution can be done.

```
  var2='*.'
  var=abcd-efj-klmnop-3.7.1.txt; 
  echo  "${var%-*}"$var2"${var##*.}"
```

Should print.

```
   abcd-efj-klmnop*.txt
```

The **"${var%-*}"*** removes the last dot . at the end It removes the extension **.txt**
The **"${var##.}"** removes the longest match at the beginning, remaining only the extension **txt**

The above solution also removed the trainling - dash which is needed. 
either just add the dash before the "$var" or add it in the assigment or this

```
  var2='*.'
  var=abcd-efj-klmnop-3.7.1.txt; 
  echo  "${var%%-[0-9]*}$var2${var##*.}"
```

Comment: Your solution also consumes the dash after `klmnop`, which doesn't seem what the OP wanted.

Comment: Right, I did not catch that, I will add a correction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "multiple digits", as you claimed in your post, but a string consisting of digits and dots. Hence, I would do a

```
WILD_NAME=${FILE_NAME//[.0-9]/*.}
```

The substitution expression would first eat the dot in front of the `txt` extension too, that's why I have to restore it.